# Angular 5 Generate component outside app folder on Windows

Tags: angular, angular5

I have tried all the command to generate a component in other than app folder . But angular always creates component inside app .

I want to generate component inside lib folder

Here is the structure :
[image]

Here are the commands tried :
[image]

still now working

Using an extension as in answers worked (check chat)

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you set the directory in which the component needs to be created(src/lib) in terminal, you should provide the component name as follows with out any path

> ng generate component test

this might be throw an error saying

> Could not find an NgModule. Use the skip-import option to skip
>   importing in NgModule.

then try as follows

```
ng generate component test --skip-import
```

If in case the above solution are not working, Please install following extention for vs code ide [Angular Files](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=alexiv.vscode-angular2-files). which will allow you to create the components from a context menu.

Comment: i should cd to ./lib  to execute this ?

Comment: once you are in that path, you just need to provide the component name thats all. i just tried in my machine and i created a component inside the asset folder :P

Comment: @DivyanshuJimmy am also on windows

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172735/discussion-between-divyanshu-jimmy-and-anto-antony).